# Как создать excel таблицу на основе объекта js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Я хочу создать `xls` файл с таблицей, в которой будет отображаться `js`  объект при помощи библиотеки `exeljs`.
Почитал немного документация и написал вот такую функцию, которая на основе константы `fakeData` должна создать таблицу.

```
"use strict";

var Excel = require('exceljs');

exports.wrap = () => {
    const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
    const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Sensor Data');
    const fakeData =  {
        address: "well st",
        description: "180036710",
        fromTotal: 1.365
    };
    worksheet.addRow(fakeData)

    worksheet.columns = [
        { header: 'address', key: 'address', width: 10 },
        { header: 'description', key: 'description', width: 32, style: { font: { name: 'Arial Black' } } },
        { header: 'fromTotal.', key: 'fromTotal', width: 10, style: { numFmt: 'dd/mm/yyyy' } }
    ];

    return workbook.xlsx.writeFile("test.xlsx");
};
```

Вроде всё сделал верно, но функция не работает и скачивается пустой файл, может кто уже работал с этой либой и подскажет где я накосячил

Comment: https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/JavaScript-JSON-Data-Excel-XLSX.html  похоже вроде ммм ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переставь `worksheet.addRow(fakeData)` после создания колонок и все сработает.